# Does RoboVM convert swing java apps?

Tags: java, android, robovm

I have looked and I cant find the answer. Id like to know before i begin this project, but does RoboVM convert java directly to iOS aka objC? Does this work for both Java and Android? Does this also include java Swing? Im wondering if I can convert my java game directly to iOS. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

RoboVM converts what you have in Java into bytecode that will run on iOS.

You can't run Android-specific code (anything that has "android" in the import) on iOS, so you will have to add iOS methods that do similar things. Generally you create an Interface that asks the "native client" to do something, and then the Android or iOS code handles the request for the current native client.

Java Swing should work, although I have not tried it personally.